# SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider (fatal exception: asynctask #3)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider

I am building an Android Library. I kept the code as normal android project while I was developing it and now I converted it into library project (even made a new library project and copied all the code in there just to be sure). The library basically allows user to enter data into database using contentprovider and the library returns that data queried from the database. So whatever app uses the library does not need to use the contentprovider to access data since the library does it all.
I made a very basic app that uses the library, the moment that I make a call to the library the app crashes giving the error code:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.example.testing, PID: 18991
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider thesis.thesis.contentprovider.UsersDataContentProvider from ProcessRecord{42a51b18 18991:com.example.testing/u0a272} (pid=18991, uid=10272) that is not exported from uid 10266
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2917)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4489)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2330)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1441)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:448)
at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 3 more
```

I added permissions to testapp, but didnt change the error

```
<uses-permission android:name="thesis.thesis.contentprovider.READ_DATABASE" />
<uses-permission android:name="thesis.thesis.contentprovider.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

The provider declared in library manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="thesis.thesis.contentprovider.UsersDataContentProvider"
        android:authorities="thesis.thesis.contentprovider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="thesis.thesis.contentprovider.READ_DATABASE"
        android:writePermission="thesis.thesis.contentprovider.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

At the moment I have exported="true" to see if that was the problem but no. Later I want it to be set false, since the data is sensitive.

Can anyone please direct me to where the problem might be. Also ask if additional information is needed.

Comment: According to the stack trace, you have `android:exported="false"`. Make sure that your stack trace and your manifest here line up. "Later I want it to be set false, since the data is sensitive" -- then there is no point in having the custom permissions.

Comment: The manifest is modified like displayed here and still gives the same error. Maybe it is because the lib file under the app is not updating. Though I have cleaned all projects, removed the lib from the app so it would recompile the jar file. Right now I would like to get it working and later on I will try to figure out what to do about the exported.